# Android hints on small buttons (as on the keyboard)

Tags: android, popup, android-softkeyboard

When you using standard Android keyboard on small screens, if you touch a button, you can see a hint, showing which button you hold now. How can I implements this on my custom set of buttons? Is the only way is creating pop ups on every touch event?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in popup functionality for regular buttons in Android, so yes, you will have to implement this manually. However you don't necessarily have to create the popups for every touch event. I recommend creating one popup and changing its location and visibility on every touch event.